# get and set the filter values of a multi_select in yadc

Tags: yadcf

to get and set the filter values of a multi_select in yadcf I use:

**exFilterColumn and exGetColumnFilterVal**

but I dont know how to get it on multi_select filters, because when I use:

**console.log("Column 2 filter: " + yadcf.exGetColumnFilterVal(oTable, 2));**

console show me: **"Column 2 filter: "**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi again,after some checks, I have discovered in:**function exGetColumnFilterVal(table_arg, column_number) line 4117 : jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js v0.9.2.beta.2** code: case 'multi_select': retVal = $filterElement.val(); if (retVal === null) { retVal = ''; } break; always returns blank space, and not the desired values of the filter. How could I solved it???Thanks in advance.

Comment: it return '' only if nulll, provide a a jsfiddle test page to show your error